# Confusion in the selection of Verb/Auxiliary Verb

Tags: present-tense, auxiliary-verbs

Below are the sentences 1) from scientific Journal 2) from a book. Since both are published text, however, my confined knowledge makes me ask this question. In 1) sentence two things are mentioned "Intermittence" and "variability", still the auxiliary verb "is" used why so? In the same way in sentence 2) "stopping" and "allowing" are used, while the verb "allows" is used which should be "allow". Can you please help me in this regard,

1)Intermittence and variability of renewable resources is often a barrier to their large scale integration into power systems.

2)stopping and thinking allows us to gain perspective on both the successes and failures of our day so that we can find the lessons within them.

Comment: These are awkward, probably marginally acceptable, so fix them. The fixes are easy.

Comment: @Xanne, how do you say marginally acceptable? I mean isn't it wrong in any way?

Comment: "Stopping and thinking" seems to be one idea/entity. The way you'd say "Peanut butter and jelly is my favourite" and not "Peanut butter and jelly are my favourite".

Comment: @Scripter1000, yes I agree, thanks that makes sense, but what about first sentence?